# Use multiple highlighting colours in a code

Tags: vba, excel

I managed to develop a code to highlight cells when there is a condition matching. But all the cells are having the same colour code that makes it difficult to identify. Colour code 37 use here. How Could I change my colour code in between 33-46 (random selection of colours even fine for me.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rownumber As Integer
    Dim ColumnC, ColumnF, ColumnC1, ColumnF1 As String
    Dim ColumnD, ColumnD1 As Single
    Dim subrownumber As Integer
    Dim Condition As Boolean
    rownumber = 1
    Do
        ColumnD = Cells(rownumber, 4).Value
        ColumnC = Cells(rownumber, 3).Value
        ColumnF = Cells(rownumber, 6).Value
        Condition = False
        If (ColumnD < 0) Then
            subrownumber = 1
            Do
                ColumnD1 = Cells(subrownumber, 4).Value
                ColumnC1 = Cells(subrownumber, 3).Value
                ColumnF1 = Cells(subrownumber, 6).Value
                If (ColumnD1 = ColumnD * -1 And ColumnF1 = ColumnF And _
                    ColumnC1 = ColumnC) And _
                    Cells(subrownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex <> 37 And _
                    Cells(rownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex <> 37 Then
                        Cells(subrownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                        Cells(subrownumber, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                        Cells(subrownumber, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                        Cells(rownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                        Cells(rownumber, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                        Cells(rownumber, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                        Condition = True
                End If
                subrownumber = subrownumber + 1
            Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(subrownumber, 4)) Or Condition = True
        End If
        rownumber = rownumber + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(rownumber, 4))
End Sub
```

Comment: Would changing colors to help distinguish between columns be enough?

Comment: Yes that would do. If I got 10 colours interchanging, then that would be clearly separate them. Thank a lot.

Comment: Can you include an image of the data (sample data - to get the visual explanation of how it should work)

Comment: Sorry cant upload due to privacy things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make your color index as a number, say 33, and add it to be the MOD of subrownumber.  If you want 10 different colors use subrownumber MOD 10, 8 different colors use subrownumber MOD 8, etc.

You'd also have to change your conditional to check for a range of ColorIndex instead of just one value, so you may want to start by setting all colors the same on the sheet (or removing color).  For example, if you start with a ColorIndex of something less than 33, then you could add a subrownubmer MOD 10 to 33 in each loop and never risk breaking the conditional.

So without the underlying data, I haven't run this code, but I would do this:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rownumber As Integer
    Dim ColumnC, ColumnF, ColumnC1, ColumnF1 As String
    Dim ColumnD, ColumnD1 As Single
    Dim subrownumber As Integer
    Dim Condition As Boolean
    rownumber = 1
    Do
        ColumnD = Cells(rownumber, 4).Value
        ColumnC = Cells(rownumber, 3).Value
        ColumnF = Cells(rownumber, 6).Value
        Condition = False
        If (ColumnD < 0) Then
            subrownumber = 1
            Do
                ColumnD1 = Cells(subrownumber, 4).Value
                ColumnC1 = Cells(subrownumber, 3).Value
                ColumnF1 = Cells(subrownumber, 6).Value
                If (ColumnD1 = ColumnD * -1 And ColumnF1 = ColumnF And _
                    ColumnC1 = ColumnC) And _
                    Cells(subrownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex < 33 And _
                    Cells(rownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex < 33 Then
                        Cells(subrownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = _
                            (subrownumber MOD 10) + 33
                        Cells(subrownumber, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = _
                            (subrownumber MOD 10) + 33
                        Cells(subrownumber, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = _
                            (subrownumber MOD 10) + 33
                        Cells(rownumber, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = _
                            (subrownumber MOD 10) + 33
                        Cells(rownumber, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = _
                            (subrownumber MOD 10) + 33
                        Cells(rownumber, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = _
                            (subrownumber MOD 10) + 33
                        Condition = True
                End If
                subrownumber = subrownumber + 1
            Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(subrownumber, 4)) Or Condition = True
        End If
        rownumber = rownumber + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(rownumber, 4))
End Sub
```

This should make sure that you never get a cell with the same color above or below it (unless it is the default color that you begin with).

Comment: Excellent.  Glad to hear it.